# Conditional Login Link - Wordpress - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Thanks in advanced for any help provided and taking the time to review my question. I basically just have a Wordpress site that once you login, you see your name and avatar in the top right corner and when you hover over your name an "Edit Profile" and "Log out" link appear. All I want is for a "Login" link to be in that same spot when you're not logged in. (This saves me from having to put a login widget in the sidebar).

I was able to track down the PHP file that holds that specific piece of code and find the spot where the user menu is setup. I'm just not sure what piece of code I could add so that there's a login link there that leads to mysite.com/login/. Here is the current code:

```
                            <?php }
                        //user menu
                            $user_show_info = ot_get_option('user_show_info');
                            if ( is_user_logged_in() && $user_show_info =='1') {
                            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                            $link = get_edit_user_link( $current_user->ID );
                            ?>
                                <li class="menu-item current_us">
                                <?php  
                                echo '<a class="account_cr" href="#">'.$current_user->user_login; 
                                echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, '25' ).'</a>';
                                ?>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php _e('Edit Profile','cactusthemes') ?></a></li>
                                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php _e('Logout','cactusthemes') ?></a></li>
```

Here's an image to show you what I mean as well. Top is logged out, bottom logged in.

http://6chill.com/loli.jpg

Thanks again for any help that you're able to provide and if you require further details just let me know and I'll do my best to provide them.

Thanks for the prompt reply everyone :) As requested, here's more of the code to ensure nothing was left out.

```
 <?php }
                        //user menu
                            $user_show_info = ot_get_option('user_show_info');
                            if ( is_user_logged_in() && $user_show_info =='1') {
                            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                            $link = get_edit_user_link( $current_user->ID );
                            ?>
                                <li class="menu-item current_us">
                                <?php  
                                echo '<a class="account_cr" href="#">'.$current_user->user_login; 
                                echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, '25' ).'</a>';
                                ?>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php _e('Edit Profile','cactusthemes') ?></a></li>
                                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php _e('Logout','cactusthemes') ?></a></li>

                                </ul>
                                </li>
                        <?php }?>
                        <?php //submit menu
                        if(ot_get_option('user_submit',1)) {
                            $text_bt_submit = ot_get_option('text_bt_submit');
                            if($text_bt_submit==''){ $text_bt_submit = 'Submit Video';}
                            if(ot_get_option('only_user_submit',1)){
                                if(is_user_logged_in()){?>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitModal"><?php _e($text_bt_submit,'cactusthemes'); ?></a></li>
                            <?php }
                            } else{
                            ?>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitModal"><?php _e($text_bt_submit,'cactusthemes'); ?></a></li>
                            <?php
                            }
                        } ?>
```

I hope that's what you're looking for. Where you see the comment "//submit menu", that's where the "Submit Video" button comes into play. Thanks so much again guys, you're freaking awesome!

Comment: The code that you have posted does not contain the full part of **if loop** , can you please provide the entire if loop, so that i can deliver you an answer.

Comment: Updated, thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, I think this will help you

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{ ?>

    <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(home_url()); ?>">LOGOUT</a>

    <!-- add another action as per your requirement-->

<?php } else 
{ ?>
    <a class="login" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/login/">LOGIN</a>
      <! -- give link to your login page -->
<?php }
```

put this code in header file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an else to the if statement that checks if the user is logged in. If they aren't logged then you output a link to the login page. You may need to tweak the CSS or the classes on the menu item for the login link.

```
 <?php }

$user_show_info = ot_get_option('user_show_info');
if ( is_user_logged_in() && $user_show_info =='1') {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $link = get_edit_user_link( $current_user->ID );
    ?>
        <li class="menu-item current_us">
        <?php  
        echo '<a class="account_cr" href="#">'.$current_user->user_login; 
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, '25' ).'</a>';
        ?>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php _e('Edit Profile','cactusthemes') ?></a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php _e('Logout','cactusthemes') ?></a></li>

        </ul>
        </li>
<?php } else { ?>
    <li class="menu-item current_us">
        <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>">Login</a>
    </li>

<?php } ?>
<?php //submit menu
if(ot_get_option('user_submit',1)) {
    $text_bt_submit = ot_get_option('text_bt_submit');
    if($text_bt_submit==''){ $text_bt_submit = 'Submit Video';}
    if(ot_get_option('only_user_submit',1)){
        if(is_user_logged_in()){?>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitModal"><?php _e($text_bt_submit,'cactusthemes'); ?></a></li>
    <?php }
    } else{
    ?>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitModal"><?php _e($text_bt_submit,'cactusthemes'); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why but for some reason this and the other suggestions break the page - comes up as a blank, white page each time. I'm not sure if it's the way I'm implementing it or if I'm just not including enough of the code for others to see.

I went ahead and included the entire PHP file here http://pastebin.com/YHZy2wLw in case there's something relevant I wasn't including. To find the specific area I'm looking at, you can just search that page for //usermenu. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Disregard the previous comment, I was able to implement this piece of code without breaking the site

    <?php } else { ?>
    <li class="menu-item current_us">
        <a href="<?php wp_login_url(); ?>">Login</a>
    </li>

I still don't see any login link when I check in incognito mode though :/ Not sure why

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: Sure, but if it would be more helpful I can just provide you admin access to the dashboard. If you have an email address, I'll send login info. I just backed up the entire VM so even if something goes south I can have it back up in no time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not willing to post my email address. If you want to provide a link to the site I can take a look.

Comment: Looks like you may need to edit another file. The code I posted has added the login link to the mobile menu.

Comment: That's EXACTLY the tip I needed. Found the non mobile section and it works perfectly. You're the best! Thanks so much